# Get accent color programmatically (from a module)

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-theme, android-library

I have made a custom Toolbar which works well but since I have move the source on a module, I am facing some problems:

Firstly : I can't retrieve the *accent color* because it provokes this crash :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kassisdion.lib.R$attr
```

(This is how I have try to retrieve the accent color)

```
private static int getThemeAccentColor1(final Context context) {
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, new int[]{R.attr.colorAccent});
    int color = a.getColor(0, 0);
    a.recycle();

    return color;
}

public static int getThemeAccentColor2(final Context context) {
    final TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorAccent, value, true);
    return value.data;
}
```

Secondly : I can't access to *android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.toolbarStyle* value anymore (before I use to access to it statically).

I think the two issue are linked but I don't know what's wrong.

UPDATE :

I used to override a lot of Widget and I use this constructor :

```
public MyWidget(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.myWidgetStyle);
}
```

Generally people replace `android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.myWidgetStyle` by `0` but it can cause some issues (like the EditText becoming non editable).

After a lot of research, I've figured out that `android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.*` cannot be use. (On the last update, they have mad this field private, maybe it's linked to my problem).

So my solution was to create my own Toolbar instead of extending android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Comment: I think it just depends on what R class you are importing, check your imports at the top of the file.

Answer (score 2):

To get a color from your theme:

```
@ColorInt
public static int getThemeColor
(
        @NonNull final Context context,
        @AttrRes final int attributeColor
)
{
    final TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    context.getTheme ().resolveAttribute (attributeColor, value, true);
    return value.data;
}
```

To get the accent color for example (from a fragment):

```
final int color = UtilsColor.getThemeColor(getActivity(), R.attr.colorAccent);
```

Comment: Your solution is the same as getThemeAccentColor2(), you should read the question before posting a solution...